# Why is Swift Decimal Returning Number from String Containing Letters?

Tags: swift, decimal, nsdecimalnumber

I am working with Swift's `Decimal` type, trying to ensure that an user-entered `String` is a valid `Decimal`.

I have two `String` values, each including a letter, within my Playground file. One of the values contains a letter at the start, while the other contains a letter at the end. I initialize a `Decimal` using each value, and only one `Decimal` initialization fails; the `Decimal` initialized with the value that contains the letter at the beginning.

Why does the `Decimal` initialized with a value that contains a letter at the end return a valid `Decimal`? I expect `nil` to be returned.

Attached is a screenshot from my Playground file.

[image: Screenshot of code that produces a valid Decimal from a String with a trailing letter]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works this way because `Decimal` accepts any number values before the letters. The letters act as a terminator for any numbers that comes after it. So in your example:

```
12a = 12   ( a is the terminator in position 3 )
a12 = nil  ( a is the terminator in position 1 )
```

If wanting both to be invalid if the string contains a letter then you could use `Float` instead.

Comment: The only exception really to note is when using scientific notation; the `e+` will not terminate the number, for example (`12.21e+03`) would be a valid string which would be rounded out to `12210`...